# I can't get matplotlib in python to plot a simple graph starting with X values at 5 given in a list

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following simple code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

days = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4]
volumes = [34, 50, 61, 20, 46, 48, 68, 66, 56, 86, 38, 35, 27, 28, 28, 42, 63, 41, 26, 36, 26, 38, 44, 47, 62, 42, 29, 43, 31, 50, 45]

plt.plot(days, volumes, marker='o', linestyle='-')

# Plotting
plt.xlabel('Days')
plt.ylabel('Study Volume')
plt.title('Study Volume Over Days')

plt.show()
```

This displays the following plot:

[image: Plot displayed]

There are two issues here:

1. The x-axis is supposed to come from the days variable, so it should be 5, 6, 7, ...
2. The y-axis is not even showing the proper values. If you look, it seems that it's starting with the y value of the 1st day, not the 5th day.

The plot should simply display the days in the X axis, and the volumes in the Y axis.

To fix the X axis I added the following:

```
plt.xticks(range(1, 32), days, rotation=55)
```

Which fixes the X axis ticks, but the data is still wrongly displayed on the Y axis.

Comment: You want a "categorical" x-axis, not a numerical one.  E.g. via: `plt.plot(range(len(days)), volumes, marker='o', linestyle='-')` followed by `plt.xticks(range(len(days), days)`

Comment: Matplotlib will plot them in the order they appear in the list, so it started at the first value, which is (5, 34), then (6, 50), ... and when it got to (31, 29), the next x-value was 1, so it drew the line between 31 and 1. You can do what JohanC suggests or, since you're dealing with dates, use the proper dates (look into `datetime` from the python standard library) and plot them in date order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in previous comments: since it appears your dates are from different months it will make more sense to use sometime like a `datetime` object (or in this example just a `date` object (since we don't have any HMS info)) to represent the X axis so that the X values are monotonically increasing.

On the simplifying assumption that you are observing *every* day and starting on Jan 5 this code creates an array of `date` objects that starts at date `date(2024, 1, 5)` and then adds a `timedelta` object of 1 day to create an X
axis that is the same length as the data

(if you *didn't* take a measurement every day, you could change your
`days` list into to a list of tuples of (month, day)

```
days1 = [ (1, 5), (1, 7), (1, 10), (2, 15), (3, 26)]
```

or even into a list of tuples of (year, month day)

```
days2 = [ (2024, 1, 5), (2024, 6, 9), (2025, 3, 1) ]
```

then convert thoses into an array of `date` objects using a list comprehension, for example with `days1` (assuming 2024) you could use

```
dates = [ date(2024, *t) for t in days1 ]
```

to make the array of `date` objects

Anyway here is some code using simplying assumption of daily observations:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import date, timedelta

# days not used in this example
# days = [ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4]

volumes = [34, 50, 61, 20, 46, 48, 68, 66, 56, 86, 38, 35, 27, 28, 28, 42, 63, 41, 26, 36, 26, 38, 44, 47, 62, 42, 29, 43, 31, 50, 45]

# Plotting
fg, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.set_xlabel('Days')
axs.set_ylabel('Study Volume')
axs.set_title('Study Volume Over Days')

# create a list of date objects same size as list of volumes

day_count = len(volumes)
start_day = date(2024, 1, 5)
one_day   = timedelta(1, 0, 0)

dates = []
for _ in range(day_count):
    dates.append(start_day)
    start_day += one_day
    
# since dates plot as "yyyy-mm-dd" we don't want a label at every location
# or X axis will be unreadable, so use set_xticks to place a date label at
# every 6th location (tweak as needed)

axs.set_xticks(dates[::6], dates[::6])
axs.plot(dates, volumes)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The code works as expected , but you provide the data in a wrong way, the values on x should be increasing, in your days list you start with 5 to 31 , then you have `1,2,3,4` at the end of this list.

That is why the line looks like this in your screenshot, it starts at 5 and goes increasing to 31 then goes back to 1 !

Comment: I don't think it's correct to say they have the data in the wrong order. I think the issue here is that they provided only the days of the months and not the months as well. The data most likely starts on the 5th day of January and then they continued adding until the 4th day of February. So the data is in the correct order, but it appears out of order without the month information.

Comment: it depends on the case, but in general it is a line graph , and the x data for line graph should be in ascending order, it could be a solution to provide the month data with days in a way makes it ascending.

Comment: Considering yesterday was the 4th and these are days, I have a strong feeling this data is data from the past month (the last day in the first group is 31 and January has 31 days) and they should be using `datetime` values instead of just the days of the month.